# Which Javascript key:value data structure, built-in or otherwise, where the key is an object, offers the best performance?

Tags: javascript, data-structures, hash, collections, hashmap

Imagine that you want a key:value data structure where the keys are, the value (not the reference) of JavaScript objects of this type:

```
{board: string, player: number}
```

and the values are JavaScript objects of this type:

```
{
  state:{
    board: string, 
    player: number 
  }, 
  score: number
}
```

Which data structure would offer you the best set/get performance speed? A [Map](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Map) where you would have to stringify the objects before using them as keys, or some sort of hashmap where you actually use a hash function on the key objects and then use the hash as a key in an Array or a Map? Or maybe you can think of some other implementation that would offer better performance?

---

Just to be clear, in our data structure, when it comes to the keys, although

```
const object1 = {board:'123456789', player: 1}
```

and

```
const object2 = {board:'123456789', player: 1}
```

refer to two distinct JavaScript objects, if used as keys, they would point to the same value in our key:value data structure. They would be part of the same key:value pair. That is why in the case of a Map, you would need to stringify the objects before using them as keys.

Wanted behaviour:

```
myDataCollection.set(object1, someValue)
myDataCollection.get(object2) // -> someValue
```

The current JavaScript implementation of Map does this

```
 myMap.set(object1, someValue)
 myMap.get(object2) // -> undefined
```

Comment: This sounds a little bit like an XY problem - it's pretty weird for two deeply-equal objects to have separate references. For efficiency, you wouldn't want to be stringifying the inputted key every time a lookup is performed, if possible.

Comment: What higher level problem are you trying to solve?

Comment: @charlietfl I want to implement a transposition table in a Monte Carlo Tree Search algorithm or minimax algorithm. The game state, represented as an object, is the key, the value is an object with some data on that game state.

Comment: There's no built-in data structure that does what you want AFAIK, and you might have a hard time finding an existing library that works the way you describe. You might end up having to implement such a data structure yourself -- and then it'll be as efficient as you can make it.

Comment: you'll find, in javascript that `object1 !== object2` (using your examples for `object1` and `object2`

Comment: @JaromandaX I know that, that is why the object need to be stringified before being used as keys, because for my purposes, they need to be the same key in the data structure.

Comment: if you're going to stringify the objects, then there's no reason to use a Map any more

Comment: If you are going to be dealing with a lot of lookups, stringifying the values of your objects in order to use them as a key will come at a cost. You will probably be better off building a tree structure with something like: `tree[board][player]` assuming your data is structured enough to allow that.

Comment: @Mark_M are you suggesting that instead of having a key:value collection I store each state in some kind of search tree? Worth exploring. I will be dealing with a huge amount of gets and quite a bit of sets, although not nearly as many as gets.

Comment: @Mark_M  I know that stringifying and unstringifying comes at a cost but after that, lookups in the Map are pretty much O(1). I wonder if using a search tree would be faster.

Comment: My node tests show `v = hash[board+'_'+player]` is noticeably slower than `m = tree[board][player]`, but its only significant on rather larger loops. The tree would certainly be more work, but it might squeeze out a bit more speed. Tests in the browser weren't as promising, so maybe V8 is doing something behind the scenes.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After trying a few things, I conclude that a hash table with hash function is faster than a Map. Here is my test code implementation:

```js
function generateKeyObject() {
    const board = Math.random().toString(36).substring(2, 15) + Math.random().toString(36).substring(2, 15);
    const player = Math.random();
    return {board, player}
}

function generateValueObject(key) {
    const score = Math.random();
    return {state: {board: key.board, player: key.player}, score}
}

const getRandomIntInclusive = (min, max) => {
    min = Math.ceil(min)
    max = Math.floor(max)
    return Math.floor(Math.random() * (max - min + 1)) + min // The maximum is inclusive and the minimum is inclusive
  }

let numberOfEntries = 1000000;

// Generate an array of keys
let keys = [];

for (let i = 0; i < numberOfEntries; i++) {
    keys.push(generateKeyObject());
}

// Generate an array of values
let values = [];

for (let i = 0; i < numberOfEntries; i++) {
    values.push(generateValueObject(keys[i]));
}


/********************** MAP **********************************/ 

const map = new Map();

let elapsedTime = 0;
// Set
for (let i = 0; i < numberOfEntries; i++) { 
    const start = Date.now()
    const keyString = JSON.stringify(keys[i]);
    map.set(keyString, values[i]);
    const stop = Date.now()
    elapsedTime += stop-start;
}
console.log(`Map set total time: ${(elapsedTime / 1000)}`);


// Get
elapsedTime = 0;
for (let i = 0; i < numberOfEntries; i++) {
    const index = getRandomIntInclusive(0, numberOfEntries - 1);
    const start = Date.now()
    const keyString = JSON.stringify(keys[index]);
    const result = map.get(keyString);
    const stop = Date.now()
    elapsedTime += stop-start;
    if (result !== values[index]) throw new Error('Oops, there is a problem with the Get operation of Map');
}
console.log(`Map get total time: ${(elapsedTime / 1000)}`);


/********************** HASHTABLE  ****************************/


class HashTable {    
    constructor(bucketCount) {
        this.buckets_ = []
        this.bucketCount_ = bucketCount
        for (let i=0; i< this.bucketCount_;i++){
            this.buckets_.push(new Map());
        }
    }

    hashFunction_(obj) {
        let key = JSON.stringify(obj);
        let hash = 0;
        if (key.length === 0) return hash;
        for (let i = 0; i < key.length; i++) {
            hash = (hash<<5) - hash;
            hash = hash + key.charCodeAt(i);
            hash = hash & hash; // Convert to 32bit integer
        }
        return Math.abs(hash);
    }

    getBucketIndex_(obj) {
        return this.hashFunction_(obj) % this.bucketCount_;
    }

    getBucket_(obj) {
        return this.buckets_[this.getBucketIndex_(obj)];
    }

    set(key, value) {
        this.getBucket_(key).set(key, value);
    }
    get(lookupKey) {
        return this.getBucket_(lookupKey).get(lookupKey);
    }
}

const hashTable = new HashTable(numberOfEntries);

elapsedTime = 0;
// Set
for (let i = 0; i < numberOfEntries; i++) { 
    const start = Date.now()    
    hashTable.set(keys[i], values[i]);
    const stop = Date.now()
    elapsedTime += stop-start;
}
console.log(`Hashtable set total time: ${(elapsedTime / 1000)}`);

// Get
elapsedTime = 0;
for (let i = 0; i < numberOfEntries; i++) {
    const index = getRandomIntInclusive(0, numberOfEntries - 1);
    const start = Date.now()
    const result = hashTable.get(keys[index])
    const stop = Date.now()
    elapsedTime += stop-start;
    if (result !== values[index]) throw new Error('Oops, there is a problem with the Get operation of HashTable');
}
console.log(`Hashtable get total time: ${(elapsedTime / 1000)}`);
```